# Управление EPD-экраном

Tags: embedded

Экран на основе электронных чернил производства LG.

Имеются управляющие линии:

- LE - latch enable;
- VCL - vertical clock;
- HCL - horizontal clock;
- VSP - vertical start pulse;
- HSP - horizontal start pulse;
- OE - output enable.
- DATA - данные.

В общем-то, достаточно стандартная штука. И если с тактированием, синхронизацией и передачей данных более-менее понятно, то не соображу, как быть с сигналом OE. Он отвечает за то, чтобы строка проявилась на экране - прилагается большое напряжение (согласно загруженным в буфер данным) и заряженные частички в капсулах перемещаются как-то, формируя картинку.

В даташитах (весьма скудных и малораспространённых) есть временные диаграммы всего, кроме вот этого сигнала. Даже непонятно, прямой он или инвертированный. Когда его можно активировать и насколько долго?

Может быть, где-то есть статьи на тему руления оными дисплеями? Примеры программ? Или хотя бы даташит какой-нибудь толковый? У LG с этим всё очень плохо.